# I'm getting 'Name or service not known' in Linux Kali when connecting with Virtualbox Bridged Adapter

Tags: ubuntu, networking, kali-linux, virtualbox, networkmanager

Hello I'm running Kali Linux on VirtualBox. I'm attempting to run a Bridged Adapter connection. Relevant details:

(In VM) Name: Kali Operating System: Ubuntu (64-bit)

Adapter 1: Intel PRO/1000 MT Desktop, (Bridged Adapter, Microsoft Network Adapter, Multiplexor Driver)

(Host machine) Host Machine (Windows 10) Wireless adapter: Intel (R) Dual Band Wireless AC-3165

I'm following a tutorial as well as tinkering around after reading various tutorials online. What I have done so far:

- Selected 'Bridged Adapter' from the dropdown in network settings in VM
- Selected 'Allow VMs' from 'Promiscuous Mode:' in VM settings.
- Checked 'Cable Connected' in VM settings.
- Created a bridge in Windows network settings between my Windows Wireless adapter and the VM adapter. It has created 'Microsoft Network Adapter Multiplexor Driver' in Windows Network Settings.
- I've selected Microsoft Network Adapter Multiplexor Driver in network settings in VM.
- In Kali I have changed managed=false to managed=true in NetworkManager.conf as per instructions in tutorial.

And according to various sources it should be as simple as that. When I ping a well known domain to test, it hangs for a few seconds and I get 'Name or service not known'. I've been messing around with this for some time with no success. Does anyone have any ideas. Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Why I see This?**

You see this error when resolvconf file is altered or overwritten because [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resolv.conf) file is used to configure [Dns server](http://www.networksolutions.com/support/what-is-a-domain-name-server-dns-and-how-does-it-work/),
I faced same problem and after banging my head for 1 week I found this as you can see that I was getting that **"Name or service not known error**"

**SOlution**

```
sudo apt-get purge resolvconf
```

you should see this

[image]

**Finally**

after running this command you need to restart your machine.

Comment: yes i tried this and it worked. thanks for that.

Comment: I am very glad to help you @jonnjo2005